# Previous and next in slide with ASp.net mvc and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, slideshow, slide

I have slide.There is main img for main image and many small icon.When user click small icon it show that in main image

```
<div class="hotel-galeri">
    <div class="galeri-ust">
        <img src="@Model.Images[0].Url" 
             style="width:auto !important;height:auto !important" 
             class="galeri-show"
             id="imgshower"/>
    </div>
    <div class="galeri-alt">
        //for small icon
        @for (var hotelImageIndex = 0; hotelImageIndex < Math.Min(Model.Images.Count, 20); hotelImageIndex++)
        {
            <div class="galeri-item">
                <img src="@Model.Images[hotelImageIndex].ThumbnailUrl" 
                     onclick="$('#imgshower').attr('src', '@Model.Images[hotelImageIndex].Url');"
                     onmouseover="$('#imgshower').attr('src', '@Model.Images[hotelImageIndex].Url');"/>
            </div>
        } 
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add next and previous icon.So i added this

```
<img style="width:30px;height:31px;margin-top:-11px"
     src="~/Content/images/prev.png"/>  
<img style="width:30px;height:31px;margin-top:-11px;margin-left:411px" 
     src="~/Content/images/next.png"/>
```

but how can i handle next or previous image on main image?
I need anything likes this

```
$('#imgshower').attr('src', 'NEXT ITEM.....
```

Comment: when somebody would click prev button do u want to display the last viewed image or the previous image in the sequence...?? There can be two approaches depending upon that.

Comment: hi @AkshaySoam I want previous image in the sequence.I want give <img style="width:30px;height:31px;margin-top:-11px"
     src="~/Content/images/prev.png"/>   that onclick event which show previous image